# Laravel App::runningUnitTests() return false only during pipeline execution

Tags: laravel, gitlab, pipeline

In my Laravel 8 project i have some tests.

On my dev machine all are passing, but on GitLab pipeline just one is failing.

I've downloaded the log file (artifacts) from pipeline execution and i get: "Session store not set on request."

The problem is that the session should be created only if the app is not under test, indeed i have:

```
if(!$request->has('need_token') && !App::runningUnitTests()){
    $request->session()->regenerate();
}
```

as said before, on my dev machine everything is ok, and if i log  App::runningUnitTests() i always get true while php artisan test or phpunit.

In the pipeline logs, both artisan test and phpunit are failing and App::runningUnitTests() returns false.

Returns false also these statements:

```
config('app.env') == 'testing'
App::environment() == 'testing'
```

Before test execution, in .gitlab-ci.yml i also have  `php artisan config:cache --env=testing`

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Which container are you using in `.gitlab-ci.yml`? What is the result of running `composer --version` and `composer why cakephp/core` in it? What are the results on your local dev machine?

Comment: @AlbinoDrought docker container with image edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:8.0-fpm.
Dev machine:
composer --version > Composer version 2.1.0
composer why cakephp/core > Could not find package "cakephp/core" in your project

Pipeline:
composer --version > Composer version 1.10.20
composer why cakephp/core > Could not find package "cakephp/core" in your project

hmm, seems that composer is not installed in version 2! Can be the problem?

Comment: @AlbinoDrought I've installed and used composer 2 `Composer version 2.3.3 2022-04-01 22:15:35` but the error persists

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Had a similar issue and it was related to Composer >=2.2.9 + Laravel + cakephp/core, just wanted to confirm that wasn't happening here too.